# Handling CuratorFramework close method properly

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

I'm receiving a stack trace in log files when testing my ZooKeeperFetcher class. I'm quite sure that the problem lies in the fact
that CuratorFramework client is being closed before the pathChildrenCache instance. Is it possible for pathChildrenCache to detect and 
call close() once curatorFramework was closed? I cannot simply add new close() -> {pathChildrenCache.close(); } method to ZooKeeperFetcher.

Simplified code:

```
public class ZooKeeperFetcher() {
  private final CuratorFramework client;
  private PathChildrenCache pathChildrenCache;

  ZooKeeperFetcher(CuratorFramework client) {
     this.client = client;
     pathChildrenCache = new PathChildrenCache(client, '/', true);

     PathChildrenCacheListener pathListener =
        (client, event) -> /* handle event */;
  } 

  /* this option is just not possible for me */
  // public void close() {
  //    pathChildrenCache.close();
  // }
}

And the test class:
public class TestZooKeeperFetcher {
  private TestingServer zookeeperServer;
  private final CuratorFramework client;
  private ZooKeeperFetcher fetcher; 

  @Before
  public void beforeEachTest() {
        zookeeperServer = new TestingServer(true);
        client =
                CuratorFrameworkFactory.newClient(
                        zookeeperServer.getConnectString(), new RetryNTimes(10, 50));
        client.start();
        fetcher = ZooKeeperFetcher(client);
  }

  @After
  public void afterEachTest() throws Exception {
      client.close();
  }

  @Test
  public void justDontThrowExceptionsTest() throws Exception {
  } 
}
```